# Python: comparing two strings for same values (guessing app)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a word guessing sort of program and it has a word like 'happy' you enter lets say 'heapy' and it takes in H, P, Y as X's meaning those values were correct (basically wordle) and O's if they are in the word but not the right place.

I have managed to create if they are in the exact position or not and point out the space between the ones that aren't but I am having trouble figuring out how to compare the two strings to see if it contains any letters the same, example the 'a' and then to add it to the list so it would print X, _ O, X, X
X being that it is in the correct place
_ being that the letter isnt there at all
and O being it is in there but in the wrong place.

My code for this part is as follows:

```
target = "Happy"
guess = "Heapy"

# Part 1 of 3
lst = []

name = ""
targetCount = 0
while targetCount < 5:
    # print(guess[counter])
    if guess[targetCount] == target[targetCount]:
        print("X")
        lst.append(guess[targetCount])
    else:
        print(".")
        lst.append(".")
    targetCount += 1

print("---------------------------------")
for x in lst:
    print(x)

print("Next: ---------------------------------")

# Part 2 of 3
targetCount = 0
yCount = 0
List = 0
guess_index = []

# index of the two '.' in word
for List in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[List] == ".":
        guess_index.append(List)
        print(List)
```

I feel like I'm being silly here but if you guys could please help me understand that would be amazing <3

Answer (score 0):

Use a set and check if the letter is in it ... something along the lines of

```
target = "Happy"
guesses = ["Nothi", "Heapy", "Happy"]
 
lst = []
letters = set(target)


for guess in guesses:
    print (guess,": ", *["X" if a==b else                # identical
                         "O" if b in letters else        # somewhere in word
                         "_" for a,b                     # not in word
                         in zip(target, guess)], sep="") # for all letter-tuples
```

will print

```
Nothi: _____
Heapy: X_OXX
Happy: XXXXX
```

Instead of indexing by a fixed number, I zip together the two words (same lengths) so you get from

```
"aaaa"
"1234"
```

tuples

```
("a","1"), ("b","2"), ("c","3"), ("d","4")
```

to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you just need an `elif` condition to check for existence of the letter:

```
def evaluate(target, guess):
    result = list()
    for i, c in enumerate(guess):
        if c == target[i]:
            result.append('X')
        elif c in target:
            result.append('O')
        else:
            result.append('_')
    return ''.join(result)


print(evaluate('happy', 'heapy'))
```

Comment: I tried replicating this for mine and when you have as let's say the guess word as "melee" and target as "erect" it says the last E is in the word but in the wrong place, it's saying such as that the index's aren't unique, I'd appreciate any assistance, please <3